# JgraphT - Equal cost shortest paths

Tags: graph, jgrapht

I am using Jgrapht library for developing a tool and if the graph has multiple equal cost shortest paths, the path computation returns one of the shortest paths randomly every time path computation is run. What is the way to make it deterministic? Is there any way to set tie-breakers?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you happened to find an answer?

Comment: No, havent found an issue